# how to go back to login page if given wrong php GET credentials?

Tags: php, mysql, url, mysqli, get

so im given  3 variables on my login page from an outside source, if one of those do not belong in the database I want it to just go to the normal login.php page. as of right now it stays on that page and does not change the url even though the vars are not in the db.
i give it localhost/john/login.php?uniqueID=BmWDLlkcyU&compID=2&tempID=22
, but tempID 22 does not exist so i want it to revert to login.php

```
     $uniqueID = $_GET['uniqueID'];
     $compid =  $_GET['compID'];
     $tempID = $_GET['tempID'];

     $checkUnique = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT unique_id from answers WHERE unique_id = '$uniqueID' and template_id = '$tempID'");
     $checkComp = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT company_id from t_list WHERE company_id = '$compid'");


 if(!$checkUnique)
{

   header("Location: login.php"); 
  exit;
 }
else if(!$checkComp)
  {
    header("Location: login.php"); 
   exit;
   }
```

Comment: `$checkUnique` is set in this case, so you'll want to run an *actual* test like `if(false === $checkUnique)`

Comment: missing a function here; most likely num_rows. Google "if row exists mysql".

Comment: yea  the false thing didnt work @jay and how do i use num rows for this

Comment: You need to add some error checking, you're assuming everything is connecting and running well. The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) for num rows are pretty clear.

Comment: you got an answer below, whether it's what you're looking for, well... you'd need to ask them. I left a comment under it.

Comment: To OP: So, that answer below. Will we see a green ticky? *I love that colour, don't you Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: *It's a very nice color Ralph* ;-) @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Color, colour; potato, potatoe, right Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this way

```
 $checkUniquerowcount=mysqli_num_rows($checkUnique);

 $checkComprowcount=mysqli_num_rows($checkComp);
```

and check for

```
if( $checkUniquerowcount > 0 && $checkComprowcount >0 )
{

}
else
{

header("Location: login.php"); 

exit;

}
```

Comment: I think what the OP may need is an `OR` here and not an `AND` operator, given their example.

Comment: no fred, as the requirement goes like "  if one of those do not belong in the database I want it to just go to the normal login.php page ", all the parameters are required and thus we have to go for AND operator here

Comment: Why should the OP "do this way"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: question for me is a tad unclear. OP gets the final word though ;-) `if` and `elseif` say different for me. OP's probably testing now. Personally, I'd use a JOIN and cut their code drastically.

Comment: *No green ticky yet Sam* - @JayBlanchard